# wx.ScrolledWindow scrollbar is going to the top after closing subframe

Tags: python-3.x, wxwidgets, wxpython

In my app I need to make around 150 dynamically created panels with descriptions and buttons.

Each button will show another url in new window.

When you scroll main window for example to middle and click button on panel new frame with url shows.

When you close it scrollbar goes to the top of main frame.

How can I prevent that and keep scrollbar in main frame in same position like before opening subwindow?

Thank You for any help!

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel
import wx.html2

class Start ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = 
        wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,800 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        self.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )
        bSizer23 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_scrolledWindow2 = wx.ScrolledWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.HSCROLL|wx.VSCROLL )
        self.m_scrolledWindow2.SetScrollRate( 5, 5 )
        bSizer24 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        for x in range(100):
            self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self.m_scrolledWindow2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
            self.m_panel1.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

            bSizer25 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
            self.m_panel2 = wx.Panel( self.m_panel1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 500,300 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
            bSizer26 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            #buttons
            bSizer12 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
            bSizer12 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
            self.strona_projektu_button = wx.Button( self.m_panel2, wx.ID_ANY, u"Button", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            bSizer12.Add( self.strona_projektu_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            self.strona_projektu_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, name='Button': self.show_web(evt,))

            self.m_panel2.SetSizer( bSizer26 )
            self.m_panel2.Layout()
            bSizer26.Fit( self.m_panel2 )
            bSizer25.Add( self.m_panel2, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_panel1.SetSizer( bSizer25 )
            self.m_panel1.Layout()
            bSizer25.Fit( self.m_panel1 )
            bSizer24.Add( self.m_panel1, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

            self.m_scrolledWindow2.SetSizer( bSizer24 )
            self.m_scrolledWindow2.Layout()
            bSizer24.Fit( self.m_scrolledWindow2 )
            bSizer24.Layout()

        bSizer23.Add( self.m_scrolledWindow2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( bSizer23 )
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )


    def show_web( self, event,  ):
        dialog = MyBrowser(None) 
        dialog.browser.LoadURL('https://google.com') 
        dialog.Show() 


class MyBrowser(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
        self.Bind ( wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.on_close )
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
        sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
        self.SetSizer(sizer) 
        self.SetSize((1000, 700)) 

    def on_close ( self, event ):    
        self.Destroy()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = Start(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: which python and wxpython version? which platform?

Comment: wxpython 4.0.1, Python 3.6.4, Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: can you create a minimal C++ sample that reproduces the issue? Do you have access to a previous OSX version? Do you have access to another OS (Windows or Linux)? Did you build wxPython yourself or installed it thru the OSX package manager?

Comment: I don't know C++ so I can't create example and I don't have access to previous OS X and another OS. wxPython is installed via pip. It looks like scrollbar is going to top when python redraw frame (it happens too when I switch Mac OS desktops). If fink the solution is to get scrollbar position before redrawing a frae and then set it on that position after redrawing.

Comment: yes, but it looks like a workaround. I guess for now it will do. And maybe you can try to ask on the wxpython ML - maybe someone will have an idea? Just provide the OS and the versions along with the code you posted here. And maybe sone will even be able to test it on the other platforms as well.

Comment: I will add this to ML. Any idea how to workaround the problem?